# How to force fullscreen image at startup on DEBIAN 12

Tags: debian, systemd, fullscreen

Under Debian 12 I use a script at startup via `systemd`, the latter launches a script. And it performs the following functionality: waiting for a removable device to be mounted, if detected, launching an antivirus scan, announcing the result. The user is informed of the steps via a full-screen image.

Problem: when starting I have the dash at the bottom and the desktop window reduced with two windows: terminal and the image I wanted in full screen.

- Service: `/usr/lib/systemd/user/usb_scan.service`

  ```ini
  [Unit]
  Description= French verbose
  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/home/X/script.sh
  Environment=DISPLAY=:0
  [Install]
  WantedBy=graphical.target
  ```
- script with only the function that calls the command:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  show_fullscreen_info() {
           eog --fullscreen "$1"
  }

  show_fullscreen_info "/home/X/image.png"
  ```

I imagine you see that I am a beginner, I thank you for your help.
Sincerely

**EDIT**

I try with a XFCE environment and it works well there.

Comment: I don't have a great answer yet, but since you're running on the `--user` bus, `Environment=DISPLAY=...` shouldn't be required.  It's inherited from the user's session.

Comment: Just tried this out and couldn't reproduce.  My setup was: `~/.config/systemd/user/pic.service`.  The service had `[Service] ExecStart=eof --fullscreen %h/Pictures/fac.png` and I started it with `systemctl --user start pic`.  Maybe your picture didn't exist when the command executed.

Comment: @Stewart : Yes it's useless, i leave it i don't know why..  A try with XFCE Environment and it's work well.